# Solr when i want to add document i have error 404

Tags: java, solr, solrj

can show solr dashboard in browser in

```
http://localhost:8984/solr/#/
```

So, when I want to add my object "document" i show this error in console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8984/solr: Expected mime type application/xml but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/update</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not Found</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:152)
    at com.mycompany.solrmain.SolrMain.main(SolrMain.java:36)
```

My code:

```
        String urlString = "http://localhost:8984/solr/";
        HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
        solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());

        SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
        document.addField("id", "123456");
        document.addField("name", "Kenmore Dishwasher");
        document.addField("price", "599.99");
        solr.add(document);
        solr.commit();
```

Problem place:

```
solr.add(document)
```

---

Tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the url for `HttpSolrClient` is correct? Note that a url that works in the browser is not necessarily what you need for an API call, i.e. the url might be incomplete.

Comment: Looks like you're missing your collection (the one where you actually want to add the document) from the URI.

Comment: Tell me what the link should be?

Comment: That would depend on the name of your collection; i.e. what collection you want to add the document into.

Comment: I don't know which one I want to add, but which one can I?

Comment: @Even that's something you should know as your application (i presume) will index there and, eventually, search from there. Anyhow, in the dashboard, on the left side, you should see a combo box with all collections/indexes you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the collection.
For example:

```
solr.add("films", document);
```

[Solr Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeX2A.png)